# Rolling back multiple transactions with JDBC

Tags: jdbc, transactions

Is it possible to rollback multiple already-commited transactions with JDBC?

According to this link here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html savepoints are only active for the current transaction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Already committed individual or multiple transactions (unlike savepoints!) are not possible on any databases as far as I know, definitely not on Oracle. Yes, savepoints are relevant only for the current transaction.

I'm not sure what your problem is but if you want to look at old values of a recently committed table you could use [SELECT AS OF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_flashback.htm#i1008579) or similarly, flashback the whole table or even the database.

If you think about it for a while there are lots of constrains while individual transactional rollbacks are sometimes **logically impossible** without violating a whole lot of data integrity rules...